# Proofs using vector properties

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
How do I show that

$$\|a-b\| \le \|a-c\|+\|c-b\|$$

and

$$\|a \times b\|^2=\|a\|^2\|b\|^2-(a\cdot b)^2$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1):** Triangle inequality:

$$\|a-b\|=\|a-c+c-b\|\le \|a-c\|+\|c-b\|$$

**(2):** By definition of cross product and Pythagoras ($\sin(\theta)^2+\cos(\theta)^2=1$):

$$\|a\times b\|^2=\|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 \sin(\theta)^2 = \|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 - \|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 \cos(\theta)^2 = \|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 - (a\cdot b)^2$$

Comment: while this is the answer I'm looking for, can you explain how Pythagoras Theorem is used to obtain $||a||^2||b||^2 cos^2 \theta$? and how that becomes $(a\cdot b)^2$

Comment: @John Pythagoras: $\sin(\theta)^2=1-\cos(\theta)^2$. Definition of the dot product: $a\cdot b=\|a\| \|b\| \cos(\theta)$.